# "too much of a" or "too much a"

Tags: prepositions

> He was too much an incredible person to be fooled like that.
>
> He was too much of an incredible person to be fooled like that.

Can we omit the "of" here, or is it necessary to be added. I think I saw some authors omit the "of" here, but I am not sure if it was a mistake or not.

Comment: I would keep the "an". To my UK senses the shorter version does not read correctly.

Comment: I would keep the "of". Perhaps that's what @AdrianHHH meant too.

Comment: Thanks @OldBrixtonian, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: I don't think "incredible" is a very suitable word in this context anyway, so I checked in Google Books for the same example using "clever". As I expected, neither [*too much a clever person*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+too+much+a+clever+person+to%22) nor [*too much **of** a clever person*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+too+much+of+a+clever+person+to%22) got any hits. But there were several for [***much too clever a person***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+much+too+clever+a+person+to%22), which to me is far more natural here.

Comment: ...but per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+big+of+a+problem%2Ctoo+big+a+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20big%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20big%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctoo%20big%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20big%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0), including ***of*** in the construction ***too much [of] an X*** has only really taken off in recent decades (primarily in the US, not UK). It sounds to me like a "folksy affectation", and I think learners would be wise to avoid using it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The "of" can be optional: "He was too good a person to be bribed" sounds fine to me (American English). But putting "of" after "good" makes the structure clearer.

"Too much an incredible person to be fooled" sounds clunky, though; I would use "of".